# Html Status for Leads

Tags: reporting, email, custom-report-type

I want to generate a report for leads object, that means how many times customer open the mails, for accounts,contacts i generated a report for leads i think the option is available or not..?? if means can anyone give me suggestions how to generate a report on lead object

My accounts,contacts report like below format i want to track for leads like below report

[image]

Comment: Sathya can you please stop using the salesforce-crm tag unless you truly can not come up with any more specific tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember "Lead: Opened" indicates that owner/assigned user has viewed lead's reord. It won't tell you anything about email deliverability, spam campaign success rate etc.

You can [track HTML emails](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_track.htm&language=en_US) - plain text emails won't have it.

Salesforce uses [web bugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug) (also called "tracking pixels") for that. Don't treat the numbers you see there as something reliable. Many modern email clients block images from external servers so the message cannot "ping back".

The relevant report type is under Activities -> HTML Email Status. Non System Administrators might have problems accessing it (common cheat is to schedule the report or dashboard based on it to be emailed to regular users).

[image: Sample image displayed when that rep. type is selected]

Alternative to this might be Content Deliveries (if you're using Salesforce Content), they allow tracking too + the user has to click some link to get the document so it's more accurate. And I'm sure there are even more sophisticated solutions on AppExchange or maybe witin ExactTarget...

---

While you're at this topic check also info about [bounced emails](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h3P7AAI). There's a decent blog post that goes bit more in-depth about it: http://www.shellblack.com/administration/email-deliverabilty-and-html-status-reports/